# Вывод сообщений об ошибках через JS и Request-ов

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

есть форма уже созданная на сайте, нужно было приделать на ту же страницу уже другую форму, по функционалу они выполняют одно и то же, отправка почты к владельцу сайта, но с разными параметрами.
Воспользовался уже существующим роутом

```
Route::post('/send', 'MailController@send')->name('mail.send');
```

Тем же контроллером для отправки формы

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\MailRequest;
use App\Mail\MailSend;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class MailController extends Controller
{

    public function send(Request $request, MailRequest $mailRequest)
    {
        $mailData = $request->all();
        $mail = ['eliseevsu@gmail.com'];
        Mail::to($mail)->send(new MailSend($mailData));
        return response()->json([
            'successful'=>"<div class='message'>Спасибо, за обращение! <br> Мы ответим Вам совсем скоро.</div>"
        ]);
    }
}
```

Дополнил файл Request для моей формы

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class MailRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        switch($this->method())
        {
            case 'GET':
            case 'DELETE':
            {
                return [];
            }
            case 'POST':
            {
                return [
                    'name' => 'required',
                    'phone' => 'required',
                    'height' => 'required',
                    'length' => 'required',
                    'numberofwicket' => 'nullable',
                    'numberofgates' => 'nullable',
                    'distance' => 'nullable'
                ];
            }
            default:break;
        }
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'phone.required' => '* Укажите свой телефон!',
            'name.required' => '* Укажите своё имя!',
            'height.required' => '* Укажите желаемую высоту забора!',
            'length.required' => '* Укажите желаемую длинну забора!'
        ];
    }
}
```

P.S.До этого реквест был такой

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class MailRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        switch($this->method())
        {
            case 'GET':
            case 'DELETE':
            {
                return [];
            }
            case 'POST':
            {
                return [
                    'name' => 'required',
                    'phone' => 'required',
                ];
            }
            default:break;
        }
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'phone.required' => '* Укажите свой телефон!',
            'name.required' => '* Укажите своё имя!'
        ];
    }
}
```

И собственно шаблон моей формы прилагаю

```
<noindex>
    <div class="main-form">
        <h3>Моя форма</h3>
        <p></p>
        <form method="POST" action="{{route('mail.send')}}" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="myy-form uk-form">
        @csrf
                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input" placeholder="Высота забора, м*" name="height" type="text">
                        <span class="error heightError"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input" placeholder="Длина забора, м*" name="length" type="text">
                        <span class="error lengthError"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input" placeholder="Количество калиток, шт" name="numberofwicket" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input" placeholder="Количество ворот, шт" name="numberofgates" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input" placeholder="Удалённость от МКАД, км" name="distance" type="text">   
                    </div>                   
                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input" placeholder="Имя *" name="name" type="text">
                        <span class="error nameError"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input phone_number" placeholder="+7 (___) ___-__-__ *" name="phone" type="text">
                        <span class="error phoneError"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input" placeholder="e-mail" name="email" type="text">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-margin uk-grid uk-grid-small">
                        <div class="uk-width-small@s">
                            <input class="btn" value="Отправить" type="submit">
                        </div>
                        <div class="uk-width-expand@s mini_text">
                            Нажимая на кнопку, вы даете согласие на обработку своих персональных данных
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="{{ URL::current() }}">
                </form>
    </div>
</noindex>
```

По логике формы уже существующей на сайте, есть вывод ошибок в специально созданных дивах, они выводятся через JS и если какое то поле отсутствует, AJAX не отправляется. Вот сам JS код.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    if (document.querySelector(".phone_number")) {
        var input = document.querySelectorAll(".phone_number");
        for (var t = 0; t < input.length; t++) {
            input[t].addEventListener("input", mask, false);
            input[t].addEventListener("focus", mask, false);
            input[t].addEventListener("blur", mask, false);
        }
    }

    var token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
    var method = 'POST';
    var uri = mailUrl;
    if (document.querySelector(".m-form")) {
        var mainForm = document.querySelectorAll(".m-form");
        for(var k = 0; k < mainForm.length; k++ )
        {
            mainForm[k].onsubmit = function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var formClass = this;
                var params = '';
                if (formClass.elements['name']) params += '&name=' + formClass.elements['name'].value;
                if (formClass.elements['phone']) params += '&phone=' +  formClass.elements['phone'].value;
                if (formClass.elements['email']) params += '&email=' + formClass.elements['email'].value;
                if (formClass.elements['page']) params += '&page=' + formClass.elements['page'].value;
                ajaxToServer(method, uri, params, token, function () {
                    if (this.successful !== undefined) {
                        formClass.innerHTML = this.successful;
                        ym(48261257, 'reachGoal', 'forma');
                    };
                    if (this.errors.name !== undefined) {
                        formClass.querySelector('.nameError').style = 'display:block';
                        formClass.querySelector('.nameError').innerHTML = this.errors.name;
                    } else {
                        formClass.querySelector('.nameError').style = 'display:none';
                    };
                    if (this.errors.phone !== undefined) {
                        formClass.querySelector('.phoneError').style = 'display:block';
                        formClass.querySelector('.phoneError').innerHTML = this.errors.phone;
                    } else {
                        formClass.querySelector('.phoneError').style = 'display:none';
                    };
                    if (this.errors.email !== undefined) {
                        formClass.querySelector('.emailError').style = 'display:block';
                        formClass.querySelector('.emailError').innerHTML = this.errors.email;
                    } else {
                        formClass.querySelector('.emailError').style = 'display:none';
                    };
                });
            }
        }
    }

    if (document.querySelector(".myy-form")) {
        var mainForm = document.querySelectorAll(".myy-form");
        for(var k = 0; k < mainForm.length; k++ )
        {
            mainForm[k].onsubmit = function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var formClass = this;
                var params = '';
                if (formClass.elements['height']) params += '&height=' + formClass.elements['height'].value;
                if (formClass.elements['length']) params += '&length=' + formClass.elements['length'].value;
                if (formClass.elements['name']) params += '&name=' + formClass.elements['name'].value;
                if (formClass.elements['phone']) params += '&phone=' +  formClass.elements['phone'].value;
                if (formClass.elements['email']) params += '&uemail=' + formClass.elements['email'].value;
                if (formClass.elements['page']) params += '&page=' + formClass.elements['page'].value;
                ajaxToServer(method, uri, params, token, function () {
                    if (this.successful !== undefined) {
                        formClass.innerHTML = this.successful;
                        ym(48261257, 'reachGoal', 'forma');
                    };

                    if (this.errors.height !== undefined) {
                        formClass.querySelector('.heightError').style = 'display:block';
                        formClass.querySelector('.heightError').innerHTML = this.errors.height;
                    } else {
                        formClass.querySelector('.heightError').style = 'display:none';
                    };

                    if (this.errors.length !== undefined) {
                        formClass.querySelector('.lengthError').style = 'display:block';
                        formClass.querySelector('.lengthError').innerHTML = this.errors.length;
                    } else {
                        formClass.querySelector('.lengthError').style = 'display:none';
                    };

                    if (this.errors.name !== undefined) {
                        formClass.querySelector('.nameError').style = 'display:block';
                        formClass.querySelector('.nameError').innerHTML = this.errors.name;
                    } else {
                        formClass.querySelector('.nameError').style = 'display:none';
                    };
                    if (this.errors.phone !== undefined) {
                        formClass.querySelector('.phoneError').style = 'display:block';
                        formClass.querySelector('.phoneError').innerHTML = this.errors.phone;
                    } else {
                        formClass.querySelector('.phoneError').style = 'display:none';
                    };
                });
            }
        }
    }

});

function ajaxToServer(method, uri, params, token, callback){
    var http = '';
    if  (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        http = new XMLHttpRequest;
    }
    else {
        http = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHttp');
    }

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(http.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if(http.status == 200) {
                callback.call(JSON.parse(http.responseText));
            }
            else if(http.status == 422) {
                callback.call(JSON.parse(http.responseText));
            }
            else  {
                alert('Что то не так c этой формой');
            }
        }
    };

    http.open(method, uri, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", token);
    http.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    http.send(params);
}

function setCursorPosition(pos, elem) {
    elem.focus();
    if (elem.setSelectionRange) elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
    else if (elem.createTextRange) {
        var range = elem.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd("character", pos);
        range.moveStart("character", pos);
        range.select()
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что для формы уже существующей работает вывод ошибок, а для моей нет, толи в JS где ошибся, то ли я не пойму как работает этот обработчик. Конечно, просто повторил уже существующее решение для моей формы, но оно не работает. Может быть я упустил еще какой то обработчик. Форма кстати успешно отправляется на форму, все работает.(Если поля не заполнены, она согласно документации переходит на страницу с которой совершена отправка формы и на почту ничего не приходит).

Кастомных валидаторов в папке resources/lang нет. В файле AppServiceProvider.php тоже ничего связанного с валидацией и выводом нет. Может быть есть какие то vue скрипты, которые мне бы стоило посмотреть ?

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, что форма отправки сообщения не во Vue, а отдельно в blade.
Если так, то надо обернуть форму отправки сообщения в Vue.

Например так:

```
    <template>
     <div>
        <input type="text" v-model="formData.msg"/>
        <input type="text" v-model="formData.userName"/>
        <button type="button" @click="sendData()">Отправить</button>
     </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
       data () {
           return{
               formData:{
                msg:'',
                userName:''
            }
           }
        },
      methods:{
        sendData () {
            if (this.formData.msg === '') {
                alert('Заполните поле 1')
            }
            else if (this.formData.userName === '') {
                alert('Заполните поле 2')
            } else {
                axios.post('http://test.com/api....', {data:this.formData })
                     .then(res => {
                        //  работаем с ответом
                }).catch( err => {
                    console.error(err)
                }).finally(() => {
                    // Действия в конце
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Прошу прощения что не ответил ранее, все было гораздо проще, в global.blade.php нашел такие строки
    var token = "{!! csrf_token() !!}";
    var mailUrl = "{{route('mail.send')}}"; // Строка была
    var mailUrlNew = "{{route('mail.send-mail')}}"; // Моя строка

Как видно, человек добавил роут на отправку формы жестко в глобальном шаблоне до подключения скриптов задал переменную, я ради интереса добавил такую же переменную с моим роутом, такой же скрипт JS валидации и AJAX отправки и все заработало.

Comment: Искал очень долго, почему он не обрабатывает мои формы, а только формы созданные "ДО".